# How do I put a blank page IN summary?

Tags: blank-page

my summary have two pages, page ix and page x, but I want to just let even pages have contents, so I have to put a blank page between those two. So I need to have the summary at pages ix and xi, and page x completely blank.
Somebody knows how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\clearpage\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage`. The use of the `empty` page style removes even the header/footer/page number (might not be needed).

Comment: but where do I put that? remmenber that I'm trying to put a blank page between two pages of the summary, and the summary is auto generate.

Comment: @viniciusdenovaes: At the end of your first summary page.

Comment: @viniciusdenovaes: If the above solution does not work for you, please include some detail with regards to your automated process/summary generation.